# How to use ActiveRecord's usual has_many methods with polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to re-build some of my models to include polymorphic associations, but I'm running into quite a few hurdles.

Even something as simple as `Tag.images << @crop_image` returns an error:

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute 'tag_id' for ImageTag.`

Are there modifications I need to make to the `collection<<` method in order for it to properly use the `:taggable_id` and `:taggable_type` columns that are used with a polymorphic association?

Or are there mistakes in how I'm trying to set up the models? *Rails 5 Way* talks about specifying `source` and `source_type` options within the models and I've tried implementing those recommendations here.

**image.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags
has_many :tags, through: :image_tags, source: taggable, source_type: 'Tag'
```

**image_tag.rb**

```
belongs_to :image
belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

def build_taggable(params)
  self.taggable = taggable_type.constantize.new(params)
end
```

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags
has_many :images, through: :image_tags, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Image'
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Turns out I was not configuring the `has_many` associations correctly. The `as: :taggable` option should be placed on the join table.

It should read:

**image.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags, as: :taggable
has_many :tags, through: :image_tags
```

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags, as: :taggable
has_many :images, through: :image_tags
```

I may still need to specify the `source` and `source_type` options later on, but this fix got back into the fray!

---

**UPDATE 20200317:**

Okay, so I feel like I understand the situation a bit better now. The use of a polymorphic with a through table kind of loses its luster a bit because each of the associated methods needs to be set up individually. And this is where the `source` and `source_type` options come into play.

So with the above, if I want to allow the user to be able to call `image.tags` I need to give the model more information so it knows what a `.tags` is actually meant to encompass. It looks something like this:

```
has_many :tags, through: :taggable, source_type: 'Tag'
```

Which is all well and good, but what if the user wants to call ALL of the different types of taggables in one fell swoop? As of right now, I don't know if this is possible. Maybe you could 'read-in' the unique values present in the column, then call them each in turn some how?

--OR!--

Maybe you bypass the activerecord query method stuff altogether and simply root through the join table with SQL queries? That may be a better approach...

But that may be beside the point for now... The only way I know to do this currently is to set up custom query methods for each type. So you'd end up with something like

```
has_many :people, through: :taggable, source_type: 'Person'
has_many :businesses, through: :taggable, source_type: 'Business'
```

And then you'd have to call them each individually then aggregate them together into one giant array like structure.